# overriding parent class variable in child class constructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm trying to figure out how to change a parent variable in a child class constructor. What I have now in the constructor body, `drawable::bounce = wall::bounce`, does not seem to override `drawable::bounce` default value. What's the correct way to do this?

drawable class:

```
class drawable {
protected:
   window w;
   vector location;
   vector size;
   vector bounce;
```

wall class constructor:

```
wall::wall(window & w, const vector & start, const vector & end, 
int update_interval, const vector& bounce):

rectangle(w, start, end),
filled(false),
update_interval(update_interval),
update_count(0)

{
    drawable::bounce = wall::bounce;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what you want `drawable::bounce = wall::bounce` to do? You're talking about "overriding the default value", but "overriding" has a specific meaning in C++ that does not apply here, so clarifications would be useful.

Comment: I want to change the drawable member bounce to the wall constructor parameter bounce. E.g by default the drawable's bounce is a 1,1 vector, when I construct a wall and give it bounce 2,2 I want the drawable bounce to change to 2,2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drawable::bounce` and `wall::bounce` are the same object, namely the member `bounce` which is found in the `drawable` base class subobject of the `wall` object. So your current assignment statement doesn't do anything.

You probably want the following:

```
this->bounce = bounce;
```

This sets the `bounce` member to be equal to the `bounce` parameter. Note that `bounce`, without additional qualification, refers to the parameter, since the parameter is in the most nested scope.

Another possible solution is to give `drawable` another constructor that takes a `bounce` parameter, and pass `bounce` from the `wall` constructor down to the `drawable` constructor. This has the advantage that `bounce` is only set once, rather than initialized empty then reassigned.